# How to interpret "has a solution" in this exercise?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, discriminant

Is the following question poorly written?

> [image]

I suppose it is a translation since it comes from a Japanese institution. I am referring to the assumption "... has a solution". Given this information I would assume that the discriminant is equal to $0$ since the equation has "a solution" but the answer involves writing it with a "greater than or equal to" symbol.

What are your opinions on this? Am I wrong or should the translation specify that it has one or two solutions?

Comment: The question seems perfectly well written to me.  I am not sure that I understand your confusion---having a solution does not preclude the possibility of having more than one solution.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I thought that "a" and "one" could be used interchangeably. That's why I was confused

Comment: I don't see any discriminant in this problem.

Comment: Please tag your question properly.

Comment: Notice that the problem **doesn't** just say "has a solution".  It says "has a solution x> 0".  That is, has a **positive** solution.

Comment: @user1551 which tags should I use?

Comment: @BrianBlumberg This has nothing to do with [tag:linear-algebra]. The tag [tag:terminology] also seems out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "has a solution" in your exercise means "there exists at least one" solution. It does not necessarily mean that this is the *only* one. See for instance the following excerpt from the *[Handbook of Mathematics](https://books.google.com/books?id=uN55BgAAQBAJ&dq=%22has%20a%20solution%22&source=gbs_navlinks_s)*:

> [image]

---

Observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\log_{10}(ax)\log_{10}(bx)
&=\frac{\ln(ax)\ln(bx)}{(\ln 10)^2}\\
&=\frac{(\ln a+y)(\ln b+y)}{(\ln 10)^2}\\
&=\frac{y^2+(\ln a+\ln b)y+\ln a\ln b}{(\ln 10)^2},\quad y:=\ln x
\end{align}
$$
and hence
$$
{y^2+(\ln a+\ln b)y+\ln a\ln b}=-(\ln 10)^2.
$$
So the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)
$$
\Delta = (\ln a+\ln b)^2-4(\ln a\ln b+(\ln 10)^2)
=(\ln b-\ln a)^2-4(\ln 10)^2
\ge 0.
$$
It follows that
$$
|\ln b-\ln a|\ge 2{\ln 10}.
$$
But $\ln b-\ln a=\ln\frac{b}{a}$. So
$$
\ln\frac{b}{a}\geq A\quad \textrm{or }\quad \ln\frac{b}{a}\leq -A,\quad A:= 2{\ln 10}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{b}{a}\geq e^A\quad \textrm{or }\quad 0<\frac{b}{a}\le e^{-A}.
$$

One can further simplify that
$$
e^A=10^2=100,\quad e^{-A}=\frac{1}{100}
$$

Comment: @egreg: thanks for your comment. I believe replacing $\ln 10$ in the original calculation with $(\ln 10)^2$ fixes the problem. Of course, it should be $$\log_{10}(ax)\log_{10}(bx)
=\frac{\ln(ax)\ln(bx)}{(\ln 10)^2},$$ NOT  $$\log_{10}(ax)\log_{10}(bx)
=\frac{\ln(ax)\ln(bx)}{\ln 10}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Set $A=\log_{10}a$, $B=\log_{10}b$ and $X=\log_{10}x$. Then the equation becomes
$$
(A+X)(B+X)+1=0
$$
that simplifies into $X^2+(A+B)X+AB+1=0$. Since we know that a solution exists, we need $(A+B)^2-4AB-4\ge0$, which becomes
$$
(B-A)^2\ge4 \tag{*}
$$
Why $B-A$? Because
$$
B-A=\log_{10}b-\log_{10}a=\log_{10}\frac{b}{a}
$$
Condition (*) translates to
$$
\log_{10}\frac{b}{a}\le -2 \qquad\text{or}\qquad \log_{10}\frac{b}{a}\ge2
$$
hence to
$$
0<\frac{b}{a}\le\frac{1}{100}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{b}{a}\ge100
$$
Of course one could switch $a$ and $b$; the solution is, equivalently,
$$
0<\frac{a}{b}\le\frac{1}{100}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{a}{b}\ge100
$$

When a problem is specified to *have a solution* it's usually meant that the problem has *at least a solution*, the exact number thereof can be greater than one.

The condition under which the given problem has *one and only one solution* is that the quadratic in $X$ has zero discriminant. Thus $b/a=1/100$ or $b/a=100$.